# How are TLB's so fast?

Tags: virtual-machine, virtual-memory, tlb

When handling virtual memory you often use a TLB (I'm asking about software-managed TLB's) to make things faster. Instead of plugging your virtual address into a page table to get the physical address it maps to you can use a TLB in between to store recently used pages.

So, what you do is that you take your virtual address and look if the TLB contains your address, if it does it will return that physical address the virtual address maps to, but if it doesn't get a hit it will go to the page table, load that page into the TLB and return the physical address.

My question is: How can the TLB be so fast if it has to search for your virtual addresses all the time? The entries seemingly come in no certain order, so going through them would be very slow, I'd assume.

For context, this is the image of a TLB-lookup I have in my head (picture is taken from Wikipedia).

[image]

Comment: TLBs are hardware.

Comment: @user3344003 I meant software-managed TLB's.

Comment: software-managed TLB is still hardware (some buffer of [Content-addressable/associative memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content-addressable_memory) with indexing and parallel search); only TLB miss is software managed. - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_lookaside_buffer#TLB_miss_handling "Two schemes for handling TLB misses are commonly found in modern architectures: .. With hardware TLB management ... With software-managed TLBs"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The entries seemingly come in no certain order, so going through them would be very slow, I'd assume.

That's not how things usually work in hardware, "going through" entries isn't really a thing. Well you can do it that way, but then it's not fast anymore so it misses the point.

All entries can be compared simultaneously, and the matching entry (if it exists) can be extracted with a log-depth circuit (constant-depth if you allow arbitrary fan-in, but that has its own problems).

Comment: @Zyphicx software managed TLB just means the hardware does not do page-walking but generates an interrupt on a TLB-miss and lets software do it. It's still a hardware cache, just filled by software. Completely implementing a TLB in software is not a thing, except for emulation.

Comment: I see, thank you for explaining! It did seem quite odd for a software TLB to be so fast.

Answer (score 0):

The TLB is just a cache. The idea behind a cache is that it's easier to search a small number of recent references rather than a larger, more "distant", number of unprecendened references.

If I understand, your question is more: ["why is caching fast?"](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/234253/why-is-cpu-cache-memory-so-fast)

Perhaps someone can explain from an architecture standpoint better than I?